# how do I change the back color of my thumbnail?

Tags: html, css, thumbnails

How to change the background color of my thumbnails

```
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <h4> Het islamitisch Centrum Helmond</h4>
                <p>Thumbnail caption...</p>
            </div> 


        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <h4> Het islamitisch Centrum Helmond</h4>
                <p>Thumbnail caption...</p>
            </div>
```

I got my css file where a backcolor is and still the color is white

Comment: how did you set the `background-color` for `.thumbnail`?

Comment: .thumbnail{
 background: #099801;
 float: left;
 margin: 20px 20px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
}

Comment: If you're using a modern browser, right-click on a thumbnail and select "Inspect element", then you can see what styles have been applied to that element and find out if there is a rule that overrides your general style. Also, `<div>` placed directly inside an `<ul>` is invalid HTML. `<ul>`s can only contain `<li>` elements.

Comment: Please avoid pleas for help in your questions.

Comment: could it be that you meant to use `padding: 20px;` rather than `margin: 20px 20px;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.thumbnail{ background: #099801 !important;` if you can't find what other rule overrides this one.